# page with params between search and show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this page that shows a result of events with a button that takes you to the eventid (which has a list of prices)

What im wanting to do is one of my api's is only showing all tickets available (how considerate). So i'm having to adjust to them.

What im wanting (and have made but not put in yet) is to have a page inbetween the search results and the `show.html.erb`

This page has a bunch of buttons on it, Asking how many tickets your looking for. e.g. `2 tickets for the event`.

Now what im wondering is how i can go about this?

Currently the button is linked up like this (on the search results page)

```
  <%= link_to 'Compare', event_path(event.id), class: "btn btn-info" %>
```

However what im going to want to do is have this button link off to a page called `ticket_numbers.html.erb` This will sit inbetween these two pages and when a user clicks said button on that page it shall allow me to use the number in the view and related jquery files.

Any help would be great!!

Thanks
Sam

Comment: What did you try and what happened?

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is *pagination*.

Comment: No i am not looking for pagination, If i was looking for this i would have asked `How do i make one long table split across multiple pages.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define a route for this new page:

```
match '/ticket_numbers' => 'controllerName#ticket_numbers'
```

And to create the file `ticket_numbers.html.erb` on the corresponding view folder.After this your new page will work.

If you need any controller logic define a method `ticket_numbers` on the corresponding controller:

```
class controllerNameController < ApplicationController
  def ticket_numbers
  end
end
```

Comment: Even though you got downvoted, I believe This is something along the lines of what i need, However you havent added the method of getting the number button clicked on into the existing show html.erb. Could this be achieved as part of the parameter